# Can a recursive function have a different call stack limit when it is called by another function?

Tags: javascript, callback, callstack

With this functions

```
var a = function(s) { s = s+1; console.log(s); a(s); }
var bz = function() { a(1) }
```

In the web console of my browser (Mozilla Iceweasel 38.6.1)

- if I run a(1), I get a result that varies around 18000 results
- if I run bz(), I get something that varies around 4000 results

Try it. Is it the same for you? Do you know why bz() would give 4000 instead of 18000 results?

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous about your code.

Comment: In `bx`, shouldn't it call `a(x)` ?

Comment: ok, so what does asynchrous mean if it is not doing stuff in another stack, out of the main thread, by delegate the job to another function?

Comment: oh sorry laurent, a typo, yes

Comment: Asychronous means, in the simplest case, that something adds a new job to the job queue. The call stack has nothing to do with the job queue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Each thread has a single call stack. As long as you're not asking for a different thread to execute your function, then everything is going to happen according to this single call stack.

Comment: great link Felix didnt read yet, seems the aside question about async stuff is obsolete since Im uneducated enough. I will remove it

Comment: There are not even any callbacks in your code - you're not passing functions are as arguments. And even that should not affect that call stack size.

Comment: laurent : but I always heard that javascript was mono thread... that sounds strange for me to tell about each thread... could you plz explain this? sorry it might be basic, a link is great too

Comment: oh yes Bergi that was stupid i missed that : im not passing function as argument

Comment: You get something similar to threads with Web Workers. I don't know the details of how they work, never used them myself. But something is sure: everything will be sequential if you don't ask explicitly otherwise. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Comment: I get different results : `5644` wit `a`,  `5633` with both `bx` and `bz`.

Comment: laurent : thx for the link will read. Ya the number depends on avalaible memory AFAIK. But you got about the same number basically, for the three functions? That not what i get as explained. What is your browser please?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 40.0.2

Comment: I think the comments are of topic, so regarding JavaScript and "threads" and "WebWorkers" there are plenty of explanations in the web and on stackoverflow. If these don't provide the answers needed, ask a question. Regarding your question, I believe it has something to do with the browser's JavaScript implementation and the maximum call stack size, see e.g., http://www.2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html. I'm not sure how Iceweasel works and optimizes. Are these numbers fix for you or depend on your available memory?

Comment: Comments were not really off topic until I refactor my question in order to be more precise and ask less questions in one. Funny,  I began my journey in that problem by readin the link you gave. The numbers are not fixes, no, on the comments (of the link) they assume that it is memory related. I can understand that, but I cant handle the fact that a(1) gives more lines than bz()... I have to mention, tough, that sometimes on refresh it is not the case (but most of the time it is). Ty for your answer.